# Integrating a .so with asterisk telephony

Tags: asterisk, telephony, shared-libraries

I have an application running on an Asterisk telephony server that alters the voice packets of an incoming call. To do this, I have followed the steps:
1. I built an `so` of the application (coded in `C`).
2. Loaded the application onto asterisk.
3. Reloaded the dialplan via `dialplan reload`
4. The function is registered in asterisk by its name `SampleFunc`
5. I am calling the function from within the dialplan like so:
`exten => 0,n,SampleFunc()`

Ideally, I would like the `.so` to function as long as the call is on. Right now it just goes into the function as soon as the call connects and then gets out and proceeds with the rest of the dialplan. My question:

1. How do I get it to loop while the call is on?
2. Is there anything else that I may have missed?

P.S: This may be few details to go with. Short of posting the actual code, please let me know in case more details are needed.

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is change the audio while the conversation, and dialplan, goes on you can achieve it patching the asterisk audio codec in use.